# The pandas documentation says: "Like a NumPy array, a pandas Series has a single dtype," but this does not appear to be true. What is meant by this?

Tags: pandas, numpy, casting, series

The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#basics-series) says: "Like a NumPy array, a pandas Series has a single dtype." But this seems to not be true.

If I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 'a'],
    'B': [2, 'b']
})
```

and I call:
`type(df['B'])`

I get `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. And `df['B'].dtype` returns `object`. My understanding of the documentation is that the data in column B should be coerced to string. Indeed, this is what NumPy does. For example:

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 'a'])
arr2 = np.array([2, 'b'])
```

`arr1[0] + arr2[0]` results in `'12'`.
`type(arr1[0] + arr2[0])` results in `string`.

However, in pandas:

`df['A'][0] + df['B'][0]` results in `3` (an integer), which means that even though I'm dealing with series that both contain a mix of ints and strings, the ints were not coerced to strings like they were in NumPy. The series appear to contain data of different types. This is contrary to what the documentation would have us believe.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: The numpy equivalent of `pd.Series([1, 'a'])` would be more like `np.array([1, 'a'], dtype=object)`. Note that both integers and strings are subtypes of `object` in python, so the single data type that the pandas docs are referring to is `object`. You might consider the Series being filled with references or pointers to arbitrary python objects, which is why they can be different. The observed numpy behavior is just that the `numpy.array` constructor automatically converts to the minimum required type, which for me is `<U11`. This can be changed via manually supplying `dtype=object`.

Comment: `pandas` does not use the 'Un' kind of `dtype` for strings, choosing instead to set the dtype to `object`, and using the native python strings.  So an object dtype Series can have strings, lists, numbers, even arrays.  Since it doesn't display strings with quotes, sometimes it's hard to tell whether a cell is actually a list, or just a string representation of a list.

Comment: Another important difference.  An array's dtype is fixed; you have to make new array (with `astype`) to get a new dtype.  A frame's dtype can change with assignment.  Try, for example, making a frame with pure int values, and then assign a string to a cell.  Then check the `dtypes`.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#series) mentions that a Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding any data type, such as integers, strings, floating point numbers, Python objects, etc. Additionally, it is stated that, similar to a NumPy array, a Series has a single dtype.

Therefore, while a Series can have element-wise data of any type, the entire series will be represented by a single dtype. For instance, if a Series contains both integers and floats, Pandas will assign a float data type to the entire series.

---

Pandas provides a unique data type extension that is designed for string data and doesn't utilize NumPy object arrays. However, it needs the pyarrow library, which may have to be installed separately.

Extension Types can be passed to the Series `astype` method, allowing you to convert easily as part of your data cleaning process:

```
df.astype(pd.StringDtype())
```

Comment: Yes, this one of the more confusing things about pandas!